# Regex for keywords

Tags: regex, f#

How can I write a Regex to represent certain keywords without any letter/number following or preceding them? (symbols and spaces are optional)

I tried to write this, but it's doesn't seem to work:

```
let resWord = "[class|function|static|this|return]"
let keyword = new Regex("[^[^a-zA-Z0-9]]"+resWord+"[^[a-zA-Z0-9]$]")
```

I'm new to Regex, so please excuse me if it's a stupid question :)

Comment: You've got `functionstatic` without a pipe in between them. That will attempt to match the full word.

Comment: @cookya if you're parsing a file (I'm guessing you are since you asked a question about a regex for comments earlier) may I suggest that you possibly want to look into FParsec.  It'd probably be easier to write your app with FParsec than cobbling together a series of regex's.

Comment: @DavidB That's right, thank you, there were actually more keywords but I left only some of them to make it clearer and forgot the pipe..

Comment: A good resource for playing with regular expressions is http://www.rubular.com.  It says it's a ruby regular expressions tester, but it works for any regex application that uses the perl syntax.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci is FParsec external to F# ? Because I have to use F# only

Comment: @cookya http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/  FParsec is an F# library.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci FParsec is still partly written in C# though, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be accomplished using negative look aheads and behinds

```
    (?<![a-zA-Z0-9])(class|function|static|this|return)(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

or with out them.

```
    ([^a-zA-Z0-9])(class|function|static|this|return)([^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Comment: You forgot to group the alternations. `(<!...)(?:a|b|...)(?!...)`

Comment: @cookya: +1 to the answer above, but what it glosses over is: 1.) the syntax errors in your regex (grouped alternates use parens – brackets are for character classes exclusively: `[one|two]` is wrong, `(one|two)` is right; unnecessary nesting of character classes and missing repetitions: `[^[^a-z]]` is wrong, `^[^a-z]+` would be right if you tried to match one or more lowercase letters between keyword and start of string / line); 2.) the difference between the two versions: the first will match **only** your keyword, while the second returns three matches, the second one being your keyword.

Comment: ([^a-zA-Z0-9])?(class|function|static|this|return)([^a-zA-Z0-9])